# connect 2 different list in power app

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

2 different lists, List A with column **Vnr** en List B with column **WBS**, both containing a accountnumber.

I want to use from list A: projectname and from list B: the finance informatie for that project in a form, by linking Vnr=WBS.

Comment: Can you tell us the data/column types of these 4 columns? Also, do you want to show it in gallery or in label controls? If you can add screenshots, that will also help.

Comment: Data Type is Text.

Comment: Data Type is Text. Column are 2. In listA: column Vnr (Text) and in listB column WBS (Text). De format of the value in both column : V.123.456.50 . By this number I want to connect both lists. For example List A in a gallery and listB in a form. If I select a project in the gallery by OnSelect, dan I can see the info from list B in the form. I have tried it with ID, but list B is an existing list with only WBS as a key.

Comment: Try solution given in below answer. Adjust list/column names in formula accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Arthur, did you try below solution? Is it working for you or you still need any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

`OnSelect` of gallery item control, use below formula:

```
Select(Parent);
Set(varItemFromListB, Lookup(ListB, WBS=ThisItem.Vnr))
```

Then on another screen where you are showing form, add on label control.

Set `Text` property of label control to:

```
If(IsBlankOrError(varItemFromListB.'finance informatie'), "", varItemFromListB.'finance informatie')
```

**Note**: Use SharePoint list names and column names as per your lists & columns.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you mean that de gallery is with data form list A and OnSelect from this gallery  I write your first answer. Select(Parent);
Set(varItemFromListB, Lookup(ListB, WBS=ThisItem.Vnr)). This the gallery from list A, with projectname en Vnr. Then I have to Set Text property of label control . Label control??

Comment: Yes correct. Gallery with items from List A where you select list item. Then based on Vnr column in selected list item, we are fetching matching item from list B and showing one column value from list B item in a label control.

Comment: I'm checking the progress of this issue. Did Ganesh Sanap 's answer help you?